# ImportError cannot import send_task from celery.execute

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I have got celery 3.1.25 installed in my virtual environment and despite the correct syntax, it my code its showing an import error like `ImportError cannot import send_task from celery.execute` I know it's a silly question to ask however didn't find anything related to this from the celery documentation.Please guide me to correct this error

Answer (score 0):

1. You should provide code examples with actual error messages to make
   your problem comprehensible for others.
2. Are you using virtualenv or conda? Make sure your environment is
       activated!
3. Import the submodule and check it's contents:

   ```
   import celery.execute
   dir(celery.execute)
   ```
4. Only if you see *send_task* in the listing, you'll be able to import
       it:

   ```
   from celery.execute import send_task
   ```
5. You can find additional tips here: [Traps for the Unwary in Python’s Import System](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#)